# systemd: Configure correct dependencies with LVM devices

Tags: lvm, systemd

I have a device setup that I don't know how to model correctly with systemd:

#### The setup

I have the following setup:

```
                            ---------
                            | mount |  /mnt/*
                            ---------
                              |   A
           4. umount /mnt/*   |   |  3. mount /dev/data/* /mnt/*
                              v   |
                            ---------
                            |  LVM  |  /dev/mapper/data-*, /dev/data/*
                            ---------
                              |   A
           5. vgchange -a n   |   |  2. automatic or `vgchange -a y`
                              v   |
                            ---------
                            | LUKS  |  /dev/mapper/decr_device
                            ---------
                              |   A
 6. cryptsetup luksClose      |   |  1. cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb decr_device ...
    /dev/mapper/decr_device   v   |
                            ---------
                            |  HDD  |  /dev/sdb
                            ---------
```

So there are several stages of (artificial) devices. Step 1, 2 and 3 are necessary to mount the partitions. Step 4, 5 and 6 are necessary to encrypt/luksClose the HDD again.

#### The problem

I want to perform all steps within systemd on a per step base (so every steps becomes an own unit).

Systemd does step 1 and 6 more less automatically when I provide a correct `/etc/crypttab`. It also performs the step 3 and 4 correctly when I provide a correct `/etc/fstab`. I have, however, not found a possibility to get step 2 and 5 into systemd.

I have tried:

```
systemctl add-requires dev-data-stuff.device systemd-cryptsetup@decr_device.service
```

which errors with:

```
Failed to add dependency: Unit file dev-data-stuff.device does not exist.
```

I considered to (over)write the dev-data-stuff.device with some manual script that calls `vgchange -a ...` at start or exit but have not found any documentation to do that with a "device"-file. Do you know a way?

Fun fact: The system mounts this already automatically. I guess, because systemd decrypts `decr_device`, LVM then automatically creates `/dev/data/*`, which trigger the mount script with the help of udev. However, I want to have the dependency chain modeled in systemd on its whole to be able to execute them by hand, too. Currently, there is now way (except manually) to disassemble the whole stuff, i.e. executing steps 4-6.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: "Bottom Up" mounting upon insertion

[I have covered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731469/316835) the simpler case without the LVM layer because this was my own use case. The post in connection with consultation of the different systemd unit related man files should be enough to understand the underlying machinery.

As you have correctly noted, the LVM layer needs additional action, for this purpose I created `my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service` in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
IgnoreOnIsolate=true

BindsTo=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service
After=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/vgchange -ay <lvmvolgrp>
ExecStop=/sbin/vgchange -an <lvmvolgrp>

[Install]
WantedBy=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service
```

`DefaultDependencies=no` and `IgnoreOnIsolate=true` are strictly speaking not necessary, however, these settings mirror those in the generated `systemd-cryptsetup@.service` units. In both cases, this makes sense because of the, for `.service` units, atypical invocation/timing/use-case of these units.

Next, we make sure that the LVM layer stops whenever the underlying LUKS layer stops via the `BindsTo=` attribute. We also need to ensure the correct temporal order between these two units, `After=` accomplishes this. (note that making an `After=` statement in one unit is equivalent to making a `Before=` statement in another, either one will do).

`Type=oneshot` + `RemainAfterExit=yes` are both necessary in order to have the service behave as expected, fire off the `ExecStart=` statement(s) when starting and `ExecStop=` when stopping (`oneshot` can have multiple `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=` statements, unlike other service types). `RemainAfterExit=yes` means that the unit is considered "active" after startup, otherwise it would immediately be considered "dead" after activation, which would preclude us from correctly triggering the unit in the greater startup/shutdown chain. These settings mirror the ones of `systemd-cryptsetup@.service` (at least in my distro) and for exactly the same reasons, to keep track of `ExecStart`/`ExecStop` invocations over the lifetime of the mount unit.

In theory, `ExecStart=` may be omitted because udev comes with default rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` to automatically start a `lvm2-pvscan@<device_no>.service` whenever a physical volume appears in the system, which ultimately leads to the creation of a `.device` unit representing the logical volume in systemd. However, calling `vgchange -ay` on an already activated device seems to do no harm and allows us to ignore the udev layer/rules (in regards to LVM) and treat `my_vgchange@.service` as a fully start and stoppable unit.

Finally, `WantedBy=` in the install section ensures that the auto generated `systemd-cryptsetup@.service` unit will automatically try to start `my_vgchange@.service`, ensuring a "bottom up" chain. As usual, settings in the install section are only realized by calling `systemctl enable` (or reenable, or disable -> enable).

[All enabling/disabling unit files really does is (re)creating `<unit>.wants` `<unit>.requires` directories and placing symlinks in them, it is otherwise completely orthogonal from start/stopping.]

At this point, a custom udev rule should automatically start `systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service` whenever the device is attached, and the unit then "wants" to start `my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service`. Furthermore, systemd will try to stop the LVM service before it attempts to stop the LUKS service because of the defined temporal ordering.

At this point, all we have to do is connect the mount point in `/etc/fstab` with `my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service`. An entry would look like this:

```
/dev/lvmvg/lv    /mnt/lv    ext4    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.wanted-by=my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service,x-systemd.requires=my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service,x-systemd.after=my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service    0 2
```

The mount point still implicitly `BindsTo=` the `.device` unit representing the LVM logical volume, thereby ensuring that it is stopped whenever the underlying device stops/vanishes, for example due to `vgchange -an`.

Now a newly inserted LUKS-LVM drive should automatically mount by itself and simply stopping `systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service` is enough to unmount/stop everything, while starting the `mnt-lv.mount` unit also pulls in the underlying units.

**Downsides**: classic `mount`/`umount` invocations may not work. If the drive is not removed from the system, systemd timers seem to somehow trigger udev and cause everything to be remounted.

### Method 2: Using a systemd `.automount` unit with LUKS+LVM

This approach depends on the automount functionality provided by systemd. Volumes get only mounted when a user/process tries to access a file under the mount point. Provided an "idle timeout" (deactivated by default) value is set (`x-systemd.idle-timeout=` in `/etc/fstab` or `TimeoutIdleSec=` in a `.automount` unit, the default unit is seconds) unmounting also happens automatically.

The `/etc/fstab` entry would look like this:

```
/dev/lvmvg/lv   /mnt/lv    ext4    nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=600    0 2
```

`systemd-fstab-generator` is now generating two units from this line, `<mnt-lv>.automount` and `<mnt-lv>.mount`, both can be found inside `/run/systemd/generator/`. Unlike normally, the `.mount` unit is *not* "wanted/required" by the `local-fs.target`, instead it stands in a `TriggeredBy` relationship with its corresponding `.automount` unit (see [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)).

Importantly, the **mount options** with relevance to systemd units are now only affecting the `.automount` unit. For example, `fail/nofail` will decide if `<mnt-lv>.automount` is `WantedBy=` or `RequiredBy=` `local-fs.target`. The `auto/noauto` option has no effect, while `x-systemd.requires=` and similar `x-systemd.*` settings also **only affect the automount unit**.

Summing up, the `<mnt-lv>.automount` is started by `local-fs.target` on startup and is supposed to be constantly "active" throughout operation of the system. It watches over the mount point and starts/stops the `<mnt-lv>.mount` unit when necessary. Therefore all we need to do is make sure that:

1. the underlying LUKS and LVM units are required *by the mount unit*
2. LUKS -> LVM -> mount units are correctly ordered
3. the underlying units shut down when the mount unit gets stopped, by binding to it

Since we can no longer edit `.mount` unit attributes in the `fstab` via `x-systemd.*`, we can use the "override" mechanism to add configuration to the generated unit via `systemctl edit <mnt-lv>.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service
After=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service
```

The LVM `my_vgchange@<lvmvolgrp>.service` unit is naturally quite similar to the one of method 1:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
IngoreOnIsolate=true

BindsTo=<mnt-lv>.mount
Before=<mnt-lv>.mount
After=systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/vgchange -ay <lvmvolgrp>
ExecStop=/sbin/vgchange -an <lvmvolgrp>
```

The important difference is that this time, its lifetime is bound to the "upper level" `.mount` unit. `Before=` is not really necessary because it's equivalent to the `After=` directive in the mount unit. `After=` places the LVM service after LUKS unit.

Finally, we append to the generated LUKS service unit by calling `systemctl edit systemd-cryptsetup@<luksvol>.service`

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=<mnt-lv>.mount
Before=<mnt-lv>.mount
```

Like the LVM service, both are now stopped whenever the mount unit is stopped, while both are required by the mount unit whenever it is activated. All three units are activated and deactivated in the correct order.